# IntelliJ Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

Tags: android, graph, intellij-idea, android-manifest, shared-libraries

I am working on a project in IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.2 built from AndroidPlot sourcecode and a modified data injector.  Build target is Android 3.1 APIs Level 12 on a rooted & ClockworkMod(ed) Galaxy Tab 10.1 P7510 16gb WiFi.  Logcat (Debug level) filters to this error:

> 03-19 23:05:54.199: ERROR/PackageManager(290): Package Dynamic.XY
>   requires unavailable    shared library libs.com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot;
>   failing!

I have the androidplot-0.4.4-release .jar sideloaded through Windows Explorer and added as a library through IntelliJ's right click dialog.  Both instances of the library I've found in Module Settings are scoped as 'Provided'

My AndroidManifest:

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:debuggable="true"
          android:process="Dynamic.XY"
          android:installLocation="auto"
          android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
          package="Dynamic.XY">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="12"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>
    <permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>    <android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="DynamicXYPlotExample" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
              android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:excludeFromRecents="false"
              android:exported="false"
              android:launchMode="standard"
              android:name="MyActivity"
              android:stateNotNeeded="false"
              android:allowTaskReparenting="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="libs.com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="libs.com.androidplot.xy.XYSeries" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="libs.com.androidplot.xy.XYStepMode" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="libs.com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="libs.com.androidplot.Plot" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="libs.com.androidplot.xy.BoundaryMode" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="android.app.Activity" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="android.graphics.Color" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="android.os.Bundle" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="android.util.Log" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="java.io.IOException" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="java.io.InputStream" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"    android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="java.lang.reflect.Method" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="java.util.Observable" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="java.util.Observer" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-library android:name="java.text.DecimalFormat" android:required="true"/>
    </application>
</manifest>**
```

Comment: and do you have the libs.com.androidplot.xy.XYPlo library in the package?

Comment: Yes, I've tried reloading all included libraries, with the exception of the APIs, is it possible I need some .jar other than the release?

Answer (score 1):

Omit the uses-library lines on your manifest.

[uses-library](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html) is used for accessing shared libraries in the device. There is no need to do this as you're providing the library jars during compile time.